# LINQ Join return explicit type and not VAR

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ which does the job I want

```
var query = context.MasterTemplateOfficeTag
             .Join(context.Tag, x => x.TagId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { y.Name })
             .ToList();
```

Though my question is I would like the LINQ to return a `list<String>` as the Select syntax `=> new { y.Name })` is of type `string`. Therefore if the compiler knows the return type, why I can't use `list<String>`?

I would want something like this

```
 List<String> name = context.MasterTemplateOfficeTag
                      .Join(context.Tag, x => x.TagId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { y.Name })
                      .ToList();
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: `(x, y) =>  y.Name`: drop `{..}`

Comment: give a try, and we can know its possible or not

Comment: The beauty of visual studio is that when you hover over `var` in your working example, it displays the type that gets returned. I have a feeling they may not be the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well

```
   new { y.Name }
```

is an *anonymous object* with a single `string` field (`Name`). Drop `new {...}` wrapping and return `string`:

```
   List<String> name = context
     .MasterTemplateOfficeTag
     .Join(
         context.Tag, 
         x => x.TagId, 
         y => y.Id, 
        (x, y) => y.Name ) // <- Now we return string: y.Name
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`new { y.Name })` creates an anonymous object with a `Name` property.

You need to just return `y.Name` to be able to use `List<string>`

Comment: It's your choice as OP, but I'd recommend Dmitry's answer as the one to accept as it is much more fleshed out :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning an anonymous object, just return the string

```
List<String> name = context.MasterTemplateOfficeTag
                      .Join(context.Tag, x => x.TagId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => y.Name)
                      .ToList();
```